# Assist with adding React Router to existing App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

The app was working until i went to add the react router to the project. I'm not getting any errors and it accepts all the pages but nothing renders to the page
Does it have something to do with where i'm putting my "BrowseRouter" tags?

EDIT: Per the comment it was the browse router tag breaking them but now it turns the screen white when i click the nav button
index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { SideMenu } from './Components/TopBar.js';
import { Foot } from './Components/Footer.js';
import { Web, Admin, Dev, Seo } from './Components/ModalContents.js'

import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';


export default function Portal() {

    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#3F0071' }}>
            <SideMenu />
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className='mt-5'>
                    <Col className='mt-5' style={{ backgroundColor: '#3F0071' }}>
                        <Web />
                    </Col >
                    <Col className='mt-5' style={{ backgroundColor: '#3F0071' }}>
                        <Admin />
                    </Col>
                    <Col className='mt-5' style={{ backgroundColor: '#3F0071' }}>
                        <Dev />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='mt-5'>
                    <Col className='mt-5' style={{ backgroundColor: '#3F0071' }}>
                        <Seo />
                    </Col>

                </Row>
            </Container>
            <Foot />
        </div>

    );
}


class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            < >
                    <Portal />

            </>
        )
    }
}




ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

router.js:

```
import {Routes, Route, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import Portal from "../index.js"
import About from "../Pages/About.js";
import Portf from "../Pages/Portf";

export default function RouterMain() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Portal />}>
          <Route path="Portf" element={<Portf />} />
          <Route path="About" element={<About />} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
                <p>There's nothing here!</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

TopBar.js: (Where i was trying to add the links)

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';




export function SideMenu() {
    return (
        <>
                <Navbar className="fixed-top" style={{ backgroundColor: '#3A9188' }} expand={false}>
                    <Container fluid>
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#">Nerd Arcadia</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" />
                        <Navbar.Offcanvas
                            id="offcanvasNavbar"
                            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
                            placement="end"
                            style={{ backgroundColor: '#B8E1DD' }}>
                            <Offcanvas.Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#3A9188' }} closeButton>
                                <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Navigation</Offcanvas.Title>
                            </Offcanvas.Header>
                            <Offcanvas.Body>
                                <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <Link to="/Portf">Portfolio</Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <Link to="/About">Other Home</Link>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </Nav>
                            </Offcanvas.Body>
                        </Navbar.Offcanvas>
                    </Container>
                </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why are you warping all the components with ` <BrowserRouter>`? you only need to use it once

Comment: @omercotkd i was just following the tutorial and trying to apply it. Still kind of green on how react router works

Comment: If tutorial is telling you use more than one router component you need to find a new tutorial, or just use the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6). You've also a circular dependency between `Portal` rendering a `SideMenu` rendering `RouterMain` rendering `Portal` ..... repeat. Did you mean for `RouterMain` to be rendered to root element instead?

Comment: @DrewReese See the edit. You all were correct but now the nav button is turning the screen white
Straight up just trying to get different pages to navigate to

Comment: Which nav button are you referring to? What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The navbar in TopBar.js. Now when you click it, it turns the screen white

Comment: When you click the `TopBar` component the screen turns white? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this behavior that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-pascal-sz6nzw

Comment: The code in that sandbox is missing a router now, so the links throw an invariant exception.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried doing it the way you did and now the codepen isn't cooperating with the bootstrap library. ugggghhhhhhh

Comment: Remove all the `RouterMain` imports/references: https://codesandbox.io/s/assist-with-adding-react-router-to-existing-app-sr4bly

Comment: @DrewReese oh i was calling portal twice. I didn't realize it calls the page/function in the routes when it loads

Answer (score 0):

DrewReese helped resolve this by having me move the router to the index.js file and calling Portail via the route in Main